# Block Editor for CheckBox MVC with Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

You have a button that calls to a Modal window...

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("AgregarProducto", "Entradas")" id="agregarproducto" class="dialog-window btn btn-success">Agregar Producto <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> </a>
```

this is the javascript that executes it

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#agregarproducto').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $link = $(this);
        var title = $link.text();
        $('#AgregarProducto.modal-title').html(title);
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $('#AgregarProducto .te').html(data);
            $('#AgregarProducto').modal();
            $('#editorfocus').focus() // set focus
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

and the partial view looks like this ...

[image: screenshoot]

It is looking to put the EditorFor "disabled" and the checkbox unchecked (false) when the modal is executed, and in the case that the user checks the checkbox to unblock the text box in question ... it also seeks to validate that when they press the "submit" button of the form, validate that the checkbox is marked or unmarked .... in case it is marked, a value will be verified in the ... otherwise it will send the message
"You must enter a quantity or uncheck the box"

I have the following modal view "AgregarProducto.cshtml"...

```
<h2>Agregar Producto</h2>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>    
    </head>    
<body>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <label>Agregar Cantidad</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkcantidad" id="idcheckcantidad" value="false" />
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.d_Cantidad, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "editorprecio" } })
                  </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Kn_CodigoProducto, "Producto", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
               @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Kn_CodigoProducto, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "true" , id = "editorfocus" } })

                <div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" id="mybtn" type="submit">
                        Agregar Producto
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

</body>
</html>
```

and I have the following script in the main view...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var st = $("#idcheckcantidad").attr('checked');
            $("#idcheckproveedor").change(function () {
                st = this.checked;
                if (st) {
                    $("#txtSearch").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                else {
                    $("#txtSearch").prop("disabled", true);
                }
            });
            $("#mybtn").click(function () {
                if (st && ($("#txtSearch").val() == "" || $("#txtSearch").val() == null)) {
                    alert("Debe Ingresar una cantidad o desmarcar la casilla");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

My code does not do anything ... when opening the modal, only the focus defined in the button that opens the modal is executed, but I am not able to block the EditorFor from the modal view and obviously my validation does not work, I am setting the code correctly? , what's going on? any help for me?

PS: when changing the script to my modal window "AddProduct.cshtml" nothing happens either

Comment: You should be doing this with a conditional validation attribute, for example a [foolproof](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof) `[RequiredIf]` attribute so that you get both client and server side validation (anyone can override you script and post back what ever they want so server side validation is critical)

Comment: I just want to block the text box easily and dynamically, then I can use data notations for that validation ... any help to do it? @StephenMuecke

Comment: Use a `[RequiredIf]` attribute! The only script you need to to handle the `.click()` event of the checkbox to toggle the state of the textbox (in fact you do not really even need that)

Answer (score 0):

you can use begin form and keep your form content in it and on submit call the javascript  function to validate it. if validation is successfull then return true from that method otherwise prevent form submit

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("method", "controller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "validateForm(event)" }))
    {
// HTML form COntent goes here
}
```

javascript code for validation

```
<script>


    function validateForm(event)
    {
          //default is validation fail
          var isValid = false;

          // validation rules goes here  - update isValid value to true if pass else fail

           // your code here 

           // check whether form valid
           if(!isValid) {
           //if validation fails then prevent submit
                event.preventDefault();
            }

            return isValid;


}
```